# Computing the power of a number in MongoDB's aggregation-framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to compute the power of a number (like `pow(3, 6)`) in my aggregation-framework pipeline.

However, it seems that MongoDB does not provide a $pow math operator in the aggregation-framework. I am surprised that this is not provided in the available math operators.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to a workaround? Or have I missed something in the documentation that would allow me to do this?

Comment: 3.2 version will have it [natively](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33603017/1090562)

Answer (score 3):

Well, instead `pow(3, 6)`, you can of course do:

```
> db.so.insert( { value: 5 } );
> db.so.aggregate( [
    { $project: { 
        res: { 
            $multiply: [ '$value', '$value', '$value', '$value', '$value', '$value' ] 
        } 
    } } 
] );
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51ff812723daeb048e4b2f26"),
            "res" : 15625
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I can't find a JIRA ticket, so please suggest a feature for this at http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER just like this one: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8568 I have created a patch against master which is available through https://github.com/derickr/mongo/tree/aggregation-framework-new-operators-pow-round-sqrt

Comment: Good suggestion, but the number of "values" is always dynamic for every record based upon an earlier $project calculation in the pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, hence the need for a new server feature for which I made you this patch ;-)

Comment: Sounds great, but do I have to compile it in order to use the patch, or is there some other method of patching it?

Comment: Scratch that last question, I found the build documentation.

Comment: I've emailed the maintainer as well, so hopefully we'll get this included into MongoDB proper soon too.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem; in fact I needed both the pow() and cos() functions.

I saw no other solution but to settle on doing the aggregation with map/reduce functions for now, in which case I could use Javascript's Math.pow() and Math.cos().

Answer (score 0):

In the **3.2 Mongo** you will have a native [$pow](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/pow/) operation for an aggregation framework with the following syntax: `{ $pow: [ <number>, <exponent> ] }`.

Here is the example from the mongo page: `db.datasets.aggregate( [ { $project: { raisedTo2: { $pow: [ 5, 2 ] } } } ] )`